# My Mutex is not working

Tags: c#

```
    private static bool Created;
    private static System.Threading.Mutex PaintGuard = new System.Threading.Mutex(false, "MonkeysUncleBob", out Created);

    //Function that is attached to each pages "LayoutUpdated" call.
    private async void AnyPageLayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (Created)
        {

            PaintGuard.WaitOne();
            try
            {
                await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                () =>
                {
                    LCDDriver.ILI9488.PaintScreen(sender);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception f)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                PaintGuard.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that somehow multiple threads can enter into the code still.
I have verified this by using the debugger, and I can see multiple threads entering into the try before executing the finally.

I must be using it wrong.

Comment: I'm just speculating, but this could be a reentrancy issue. When you yield control to the dispatcher (with your `await` statement), you have absolutely no guarantee that the UI thread won't start executing another `AnyPageLayoutUpdated` event before the dispatched call is invoked

Comment: Moreover, according to MSDN, a thread can acquire the same mutex multiple times: `The thread that owns a mutex can request the same mutex in repeated calls to WaitOne without blocking its execution.` So yup, I think that's it

Comment: How do you know that it's separate threads and not the same thread? I would expect this code to allow the UI thread to do other work while it's waiting for the result from PaintScreen (which is presumably how you *want* this to behave so as to prevent the UI from appearing to "hang").

Comment: Cool - I'm glad we all had the same idea for failure.
What is the fix then?

Possibly a down and dirty bool lock?

Comment: @user1390652 Well, why do you need a lock to begin with? Your code is already single-threaded

Comment: I am actually writing this code for a windows iot device, and if it enters the paint screen function twice, it will issue a write to an SPI device that is already in use and issue an access violation error. That means that the rentrant layoutupdated function is a problem. I am trying to prevent the reentrance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` is not compatible with `Mutex`. You can use an async-compatible mutex like `SemaphoreSlim` or the [`AsyncLock` that I have as part of my AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Coordination).

However, if you need a *named* mutex, then you'll have to do something quite different. What that is depends on what exactly you're trying to do.

**Update due to comments:**

Since you're on the UI thread, there's no need to call into the dispatcher. You just need a `SemaphoreSlim` to keep them one-at-a-time:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

//Function that is attached to each pages "LayoutUpdated" call.
private async void AnyPageLayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
{
  await _mutex.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    LCDDriver.ILI9488.PaintScreen(sender);
  }
  finally
  {
    _mutex.Release();
  }
}
```

Comment: "await is not compatible with Mutex" That's... vague. I mean, there's plenty of things that could go wrong in that code, but I have trouble explaining how multiple threads could execute simultaneously the `try` block. Do we agree that the `finally` block won't be executed until after the `await`?

Comment: Since that function is called in the UI thread, I believe my await is redundant. let me remove it and see if that works. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Is it possible that they are executed concurrently in the same thread?

Comment: @user1390652 Yes, something like that is definitely possible with async (at least in the general case). There's no guarantee that async will actually generate a new thread. Have you checked Visual Studio's Thread and Task windows to see where this code is actually running? The behavior of await could be to allow the thread to do other work while it's waiting for a result.

Comment: I tried using SemaphoreSlim, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @KooKiz: `Mutex` is thread-affine; `await` (depending on context) can resume on another thread. Most importantly, though, is that the entire idea of a mutex is to prevent concurrent code execution until that block completes, whereas the entire idea of `await` is to allow the calling thread to execute other code.

Comment: @user1390652: From your comments, it sounds like this is called in the UI thread context, and you're probably seeing reentrancy. `SemaphoreSlim` should work for this; it is not reentrant. I added an example.

Comment: That didn't work. Inside the paint screen function is another await function. those three lines look like this... "            //Create something to render the screen
            RenderTargetBitmap Renderer = new RenderTargetBitmap();

            //Render the screen
            await Renderer.RenderAsync((UIElement)sender);"

Comment: @user1390652 Please post a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: I can do that - do you have a raspberry pi?

Comment: @user1390652: No. Can you repro it on the desktop?

Comment: without having the particular LCD, the code becomes useless.

Comment: Hey, I never properly thanked you!
The semaphore was still exactly what I needed!